# Can not record the right time to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I can not record the right time to my database. Now the time shows on my computer is 2014-1-25 10:38:30 but when I use $datetime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) and record time was recorded as 2014-01-25 16:34:02 in  my database. The column type is DATETIME in my database.I have already changed my time zone of my computer to UTC-05:00 because this is the computer I brought from China.

I have a postbutton
**Here is the HTML**

```
 <span  id="postbutton" style="cursor:pointer; font-weight:bold; font- size:20px;">Launch</span>
```

**Here is my javascript**

```
$('#postbutton').click(function(){

var timestamp= new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({

url:'post_handle.php',
method:'POST',
data:{timestamp:timestamp},
success:function(data){

//do something;
}
})
```

**Here is my PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['timestamp'])){

$timestamp=$_POST['timestamp'];
//here below is the time i want to record
$datetime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timestamp);



$Insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_post` VALUES('','','$datetime') ")
```

Comment: In MySQL Check value of SELECT NOW();

Comment: Instead of fiddling around with that, just use the built-in [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function.

Comment: @AbdulManaf , It would record the time when the row is inserted into the database?or, I test in localhost and want to record the time the user post

Comment: How much of an interval do you perceive between the posting of the form and the insertion of the record?

Comment: @DanBracuk, I think it should within couple seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't use mysql_query. It is unsafe and deprecated, [see here](https://www.php.net/mysql_query/). Look up PDO.

Data is saving ok, in the correct format, so it is not a database issue. As you're setting the time with PHP, you can entirely rule out the DB.

You need to think about the source for time(). It's not your PC clock, or the minutes would be the same, so the source is something else. Try changing the server (are you using Apache?) timezone/localisation.

Comment: yes, I test in localhost, and using Apache in XAMPP, and what do u mean by rule out the DB and I heard about the default value of setting now() function for DateTime, but I still confused that this is not allowed according to the manual

Comment: As data is being stored in the correct format, the problem nothing to do with the database. Could you confirm how you're actually getting the time? You seem to be doing it with PHP in your question, but then JS in the code example you've given.

Comment: To rule out the Server being the issue, go to your XAMPP directory, \xampp\php, open php.ini, and find and set:
date.timezone = "CURRENTTIMEZONE" (find yours here http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
Then restart XAMPP.

Comment: now I choose use php to record it, it goes like this $datetime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); but when I record it, the database is recorded as 2014-01-25 18:34:46, but now is 12:37:00

Comment: it was saved as date.timezone=Europe/Berlin by default , let me change it and see whether this works

Comment: No problem. Remember to break down issues to narrow down where the fault could be.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this directly in the database:

```
INSERT INTO `user_post`
    select '', '', now();
```

This is actually safer than doing it from the application layer.  All the datetime values in the database will be consistent.

Comment: still a little bit confuse, should I add this line to my php script and then it would insert a row into the database and record the time when the row was inserted?

Comment: This is the SQL that you would use to `insert` a row into the database, instead of the `insert` statement in your question.